# add 2 numbers in assembly

Tags: assembly, i386

I want to add two numbers  but there is a problem that I cant find it please help me!

Thanks

```
.model small
.stack
.data

        data1 dw 6
        data2 dw 8
.code

main:

mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax
mov ax, data1
add ax, data2
add dx,ax
sub dx,'0'
mov ah,09h
int 21h
mov ah,1
int 21h

end main
```

Comment: what are you seeing?  what do you expect to see?

Answer (score 2):

`dx` is uninitialized and contains junk at `add dx, ax`.

Answer (score 0):

```
mov ah, 9
int 21h
```

This will print a $-terminated string pointed to by `dx`. We don't quite know what's in `dx` at this point, but it is highly unlikely that it points to a $-terminated string representing your number!

You were doing fine up to adding the two numbers. `ax` should hold 14, or 0Eh. Here's a "trick" to print two digits in `al`...

```
; split the number in al
; "tens" place in ah, "ones" place in al
aam
; convert both digits from a "number"
; to ascii characters representing the numbers
add ax, 3030h
; we want to print leftmost character first
; so swap 'em
xchg al, ah
; print al
int 29h
; swap 'em back
xchg al, ah
; print al
int 29h
; please exit cleanly!
```

That's "from memory" which is getting pretty shakey, so could be wrong. I doubt if it's the way you're "supposed" to be doing it The `int 29h` is documented as "for internal use" but used to work the last time I did dos. Good luck!